# using Intelligencia.UrlRewriter for http to https and vice versa redirection

Tags: c#, url-rewriting

Has anybody tried using `Intelligencia.UrlRewriter` for http to https and vice versa redirection of page. i cant seem to make it work on my site. Although I was able to use the rewrite between http pages.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me, in web.config:

```
<rewriter>
  <if header="HTTPS" match="^OFF$">
    <redirect url="(.*)" to="https://mydomain$1" />
  </if>
</rewriter>
```

Although I found with IIS and MVC, at least, that setting [RequireHttps] will handle the http -> https redirection automatically with a 302.